# Flex and ANT: Resource bundle error

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, ant, flex4

I get the following error when running my ANT script:

Error: Unable to resolve resource bundle "data" for locale "en_US"

I have tried to implement all the answers I've found about this question (and there were a lot); forcing to compile to flash player 10, including all libraries, etc.. but nothing is working.

Here is my code:

```
<mxmlc 
            file="${PALM_SRC_DIR}/PALM.mxml" 
            output="${SHELL_DIR}/PALM.swf"
            debug="${DEBUG}"
            optimize="${OPTIMIZE}"
            locale="${LOCALE}"
            link-report="${OUT_DIR}"
            target-player="10.0.0">

            <load-config filename="C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4 Plug-in/sdks/3.5.0frameworks/flex-config.xml" />
            <source-path path-element="C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4 Plug-in/sdks/3.5.0/frameworks" />

            <compiler.include-libraries 
                append="true"
                dir="${basedir}/libs                
                <include name="Cairngorm.swc"/>
                <include name="CairngormEnterprise.swc"/>
                <include name="fds.swc"/>
                <include name="flexlib.swc"/>

            </compiler.include-libraries>

        <runtime-shared-library-path 
            path-element="${FLEX_FRAMEWORK}/framework.swc">
            <url rsl-url="framework_3.5.0.12683.swz"/>   
            <url rsl-url="framework_3.5.0.12683.swf"/>
         </runtime-shared-library-path> 

        </mxmlc>
```

what could I possibly be missing? Aren't I including all libs that I need?

I've removed the last 2 compiler.library-path options and replaced it with this:
It's still not working but I feel like I'm coding it correctly because it's looking for the framework SWC as run-time shared library, which it really is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<mxmlc 
            file="${PALM_SRC_DIR}/PALM.mxml" 
            output="${SHELL_DIR}/PALM.swf"
            debug="${DEBUG}"
            optimize="${OPTIMIZE}"
            locale="${LOCALE}"
            link-report="${OUT_DIR}"
            target-player="10.0.0">

            <load-config filename="C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4 Plug-in/sdks/3.5.0/frameworks/flex-config.xml" />
            <source-path path-element="C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4 Plug-in/sdks/3.5.0/frameworks" />

            <compiler.include-libraries 
                append="true"
                dir="${basedir}/libs                
                <include name="Cairngorm.swc"/>
                <include name="CairngormEnterprise.swc"/>
                <include name="fds.swc"/>
                <include name="flexlib.swc"/>

            </compiler.include-libraries>

        </mxmlc>
```

Also, you should read this [tutorial on how to do it properly](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_ant_pt1.html).

Comment: So you removed the last two compiler paths that pointed to the build path libraries and the locale package. I thought that I need both of these. And the tutorial is what I did follow. The only thing I didn't implement from it was the runtime shared libraries and the create SWC tags. But neither of those I need in this case. I thought the error is pointing to me not referencing the locale correctly.

Comment: If my reference to other libraries included in the build path is correct, is it possible that my sdk is missing libraries? under locale/en_US/ I see the following: airframework_rb.swc, automation_agent.swc, automation_rb.swc, datavisualization_rb.swc, framework_rb.swc, rpc_rb.swc.

Comment: if you set the source path properly (which it wasn't in your code), it will get those automatically.  The 'include-libs' is for extra libs.

Comment: Right, I saw the typo with no '/' before frameworks. However, I put that in and I'm still getting the same error. That makes me think I'm missing a library in my SDK.

Comment: Look into your frameworks directory, there should be a locale folder and within that a en_US folder.  If that's not there, your sdk is missing stuff.

Comment: Also, it compiles and runs fine when I'm not using ANT. In my Flex Build Path window, I define all sorts of other libraries, i.e. frameworks.swc, datavisualization, etc... That is why I included those 'include-libs' to cover all these that I define in that window. Isn't that correct?

Comment: Yes, that en_US folder is there with a bunch of libraries. So, I'm not missing anything.

Comment: You're still not doing something right somewhere.  Please refer to the link I provided you and follow the tutorial to the letter.  What you currently have here is not exactly what the tutorial has.  Works fine when I did it on my machine.

Comment: Alright, I'll take another look. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: After reading thru the tutorials, I can see that the compiler.library-path to point to the runtime shared libraries was wrong. I've edited my original post by removing the wrong elements and replacing it with the runtime-shared-library-path. It's still not working, and I'm not even convinced I need it. But I feel it's the right way. Still don't have a solution and I'm kind of losing steam.

Comment: Yes, the runtime-shared-library-path is what is new.

Comment: It's working if I pass an empty String into locale a la: locale="". Why would that be? And I found some interesting explanations at the bottom of this post: http://forums.adobe.com/message/2671191

Comment: or a missing resource bundle file.  you can always remove it if you'd like, but it's there for internalization.